# Alinear div a los costados

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `div` que dentro suyo tiene otros 2.

Así esta pero quiero que se alineen al mismo nivel.

```css
.firmas {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-firm">
  <div class="firmas">
    <div class="firma1">
      <hr align="center" width="250" color="black" size="3" />
      <p>Nombre completo del firmante 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="firma2">
      <hr align="center" width="250" color="black" size="3" />
      <p>Nombre completo del firmante 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Lo cual me muestra en un PDF que genero a través de un botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo retorno a una vista en vez de en formato PDF( Utilizo Rotativa para darle formato en .NET 4.5.2), sí me divide el div en los 2 lados que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Copié tu código [acá](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/WNgxdPy), cual sería el problema?... yo los veo perfectamente alineados

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando lo imprime en el PDF sí se me descolocan como en la imagen

Comment: Seguro el PDF no reconoce el estilo de tus clases, prueba borrando `class="firmas"` y ahí mismo pon `style="..."`, en donde los estilos serían los que definiste a tu clase `firmas`

Comment: No, tampoco así

Comment: no tiene estilos pero igual ya lo intente como me dijiste y nada

Comment: Prueba agregando el ancho de `firma1 firma2` el `width: 49%;`

Comment: no, tampoco no me deja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considera revisar lo siguiente:

- Veo un `<div>` sin cerrar.
- Usas etiquetas `<div>`, `<hr>` y `<p>` que por defecto son elementos de bloque.
- Si usas librerías externas para generar el pdf, muchas no aceptan estilos `CSS` o solo aceptan estilos en línea.

Te dejo una propuesta usando menos elementos y estilos en línea. Siéntete libre de experimentar con la propuesta y dejar los comentarios que consideres necesarios.

```html
<div class="footer-firm" style="text-align: center;">
  <p style="display: inline; border-top: 3px solid black; margin: 10px;">
    Nombre completo del firmante 1
  </p>
  <p style="display: inline; border-top: 3px solid black; margin: 10px;">
    Nombre completo del firmante 2
  </p>
</div>
```